# Batch file to run ps Scripts

Tags: powershell, batch-file

So I have a Folder containing powershell scripts, I then run one script and it copies to a new directory and runs the main script, this in turn copies the remaining scripts and runs.

This has been tested in both ISE and visual Studio code and they work fine, however when I use the batch file to run the first script it carries out the first copy great then the others it fails to find, advising that c:\ was the root. not where the scripts actually are.

I am unable to define where the scripts will be, just in the same folder that the first script is, hence the copy.

I am using $PSScript root to determine the root directory, this shows the directory of the first script.

As mentioned, it works great as a standalone, however I want to integrate it so that users only need click on a icon.

**First Script**

```
$Script:E0 =  $PSScriptRoot 
$Script:Es =  $PSScriptRoot  +"\" + "Main Script.psm1"
$Script:Ma32 = "C:\Temp\Scripts"
$script:E1 = "\"
$Script:E2 =  "Main Script.psm1"
$Script:E3 = $Ma32 + $E1 + $E2
$Script:E4 = $Ma32 + "\Errors\"

Function Run{
copy-item $Es $Ma32
Import-Module $E3 -force
}
```

**Second Script**

```
$M = "\Members_Complete.psm1"
$Script:Sc1 = $E0 + $M
$Script:Ns1 = $PSScriptRoot + $F
Function Get-Scripts{
copy-item $Sc1 $Ma32
}
```

So it copies fine into c:\temp\Scripts on the first script but on the second one it fails because it is looking at c:\ and not the previous directory.

Comment: Sorry for asking, seems I needed to make $Script:E0 =  $PSScriptRoot into a global variable so it reads $Global:E0 =  $PSScriptRoot so it can be read throughout the rest of the modules

Comment: I think you should pass the path to the sub-scripts as parameters, to make sure the next script has the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I needed to make $Script:E0 = $PSScriptRoot into a global variable so it reads $Global:E0 = $PSScriptRoot so it can be read throughout the rest of the modules